# writing (for and while) loop program in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have to write a program in python about this problem:

> Ask the user for an initial balance for their holiday club savings
>   account.  The user is to be prompted for 11 deposit amounts.  Output
>   the final amount in the account.

This is what I have so far and I am lost. I don't know what to add in order to get the final amount. I also don't know how to make the numbers for the 11 deposits show.

```
balance = int(input("Enter initial balance: $"))
count = 1
numDep = 11
finalAmount = balance+numDep
while count <= 11:
    n = int(input("Enter deposit #:")) # this needs to show deposits numbers up to 11
    count += 1

print("Original price: $", balance)
print("Final Amount: $", finalAmount)
```

That is all I have for writing the program using a `while-loop`. I still need to write it using `for-loop`.

Comment: why are adding 11 to numDep ?

Comment: `finalAmount=12` would be exactly the same as what you have ... since you are never changing it im sure it always orints 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the total.

```
balance = int(input("Enter initial balance: $ "))
count = 1
total =0
while count <= 11:
    n = int(input("Enter deposit %s #: " %(count))) 
    count += 1
    total += n #keep on adding deposit amounts.


print("Original price: $ %d" %balance)
print("Final Amount: $ %d" %(total + balance) )
```

With For loop:

```
balance = int(input("Enter initial balance: $ "))
for i in range(11):
    n = int(input("Enter deposit #: %s " %(i)))
    total +=n

print("Original price: $ %d" %balance)
print("Final Amount: $ %d" %(total + balance) )
```

Comment: He asked for it as a for loop.  And, `for i in range(11)` will iterate 11 times.

Comment: but to me his while loop implementation seems wrong. He initially did ask for both.

Comment: The while loop implementation was wrong.  This is a bad use of a while loop (the general problem).

Comment: this is great for a while-loop. however, how do I make deposits # show when I input the 11 deposits? 

it should be something like..
Enter deposit #1:
Enter deposit #2:

Comment: `"Enter deposit #%s: " %str(count)`

Comment: @SamG - I would disagree with you that this is a good use of a while-loop.  A for-loop can be though of as a while loop that is specified to iterate a specific number of times.  By using a while loop, you are able to remove a couple lines of code, making your code simpler.

Comment: Thank you John, now it makes more sense. Thank you all.

Comment: @intboolstring - How do I make it simpler? what lines need to be removed? Also, your code for the for-loop gave me an error which I couldn't run it.

Comment: @intboolstring he did want to have 11 deposits. So range(11) seems good to me.

Comment: @intboolstring - and the his for-loop solution also works perfectly. Thanks for the concern tho, much appreciated.

Comment: @SamG, now try both, I haved checked and corrected formatting etc.

Comment: Awesome -- Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is **using a for loop**.

```
balance = int(input("Enter the initial balance"))
beginning = balance
for i in range(1,11):
    n = int(input(("Deposit"+str(i))))
    balance += n
print("You had", beginning, "at the beginning")
print("Now, you have", balance)
```